# Crosswalk plugin not installing

Tags: android, cordova, npm, gulp, crosswalk

I am trying to install crosswalk plugin for a cordova app that am building for android version 3.6.3. 
When I run the npm install -g cordova-android-crosswalk command it downloads the crosswalk node module, but when i run the cordova-android-crosswalk command for downloading the actual crosswalk plugin. It does not finish downloading, instead i get this error

"-Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "SET ANDROID_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(which android))) && cd platforms/android/CordovaLib/ && android update project --subprojects --path . --target "android-23" && ant debug && cd .. && rm -Rf ant-gen && rm -Rf ant-build"
The system cannot find the path specified."

I've tried searching and got this person had the same problem
https://github.com/tylerbuchea/cordova-android-crosswalk/issues/1

But his answer is not working for me.
Here is a screen shot of the error[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KPHH.png)
Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Why not migrate to Cordova 4.x? There is a brand-new pluggable Crosswalk WebView support, You can refer https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html